# How to cache viewholder view references in android recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[From the android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

> This new ViewHolder should be constructed with a new View that can represent the items of the given type. You can either create a new View manually or inflate it from an XML layout file.

but then it continues to say:

**The new ViewHolder will be used to display items of the adapter using onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List). Since it will be re-used to display different items in the data set, it is a good idea to cache references to sub views of the View to avoid unnecessary findViewById(int) calls.**

Can i have an example what is mean tby caching referenences to sub views of the view instead of calling findViewbyId.  I mean in the viewholders constructor i am already calling findviewbyId. something like this:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView review;
    public ImageView iv;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        review = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);

    }
}
```

is this not correct ? how can these be cached ?

Comment: It's cached because a single View "template" is used for all items in the data set that will fill your RecyclerView, so they only need to be initiated once. What you have there is correct - be sure that any `onClick` listeners are either in your holder's constructor or handled via interface, NEVER in the `onBindViewHolder()` method.

Comment: everytime a viewHolder is instantiated findViewById will be called per my example. Isn't MyViewHolder's constructor called for every cell being created in the list ? How is it then called caching if its called for every list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted is exactly what they mean by caching the views in the viewholder. This prevents having to use `findViewById()` every time you need to bind data to it.

Comment: i am a little confused.  for every single cell in the recyclerView a viewHolder object needs to created. So findviewById is called many times initially.  But when a cell is recycled i assume a new viewHolder object will not be instantiated it will just reuse from some pool.  is this correct ?

Comment: @j2emanue yes, that's correct. Hence the name "**Recycler**View". That's why it's recommended you use `findViewById()` initially and keep references to those views (like your code does) so you don't have to do that again when you bind data to the viewholder.